# SDMtune function modelReport: Why can I not use it for object class SDMmodelCV?

Tags: r, maxent

I am using SDMtune to run a MaxEnt model with replicates. I want to generate a report similar to the original maxent output, which this package seems to be capable of via its `modelReport` function. However, it seems that this is not compatible with the type of object that is created by MaxEnt models with replicate runs (`SDMmodelCV object`), which seems a bit arbitrary. How can I get a similar output, if not via this function?

I tried running the function with no avail. I also tried searching for similar functions within the same package. I am open to functions in other packages that will perform similarly.